# Qt splitting data structure into groups

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I have a problem I'm trying to solve but I'm at a stand still due to the fact that I'm in the process of learning Qt, which in turn is causing doubts as to what's the 'Qt' way of solving the problem. Whilst being the most efficient in term of time complexity. So I read a file line by line ( file qty ranging between 10-2000,000). At the moment my approach is to dump ever line to a `QVector`.

```
Qvector <QString> lines;
lines.append("id,name,type");
lines.append("1,James,A");
lines.append("2,Mark,B");
lines.append("3,Ryan,A");
```

Assuming the above structure I would like to give the user with three views that present the data based on the type field. The data is comma delimited in its original form. My question is what's the most elegant and possibly efficient way to achieve this ?

Note: For visual aid , the end result kind of emulates Microsoft access. So there will be the list of tables on the left side.In my case these table names will be the value of the grouping field (A,B). And when I switch between those two list items the central view (a table) will refill to contain the particular groups data.

Should I split the data into x amount of structures ? Or would that cause unnecessary overhead ?

Would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, you'll want to have some sort of a data model that implements `QAbstractItemModel` that exposes the data, and one or more views connected to it to display it.

If the data doesn't have to be editable, you could implement a custom table model derived from `QAbstractTableModel` that maps the file in memory (using `QFile::map`), and incrementally parses it on the fly (implement `canFetchMore` and `fetchMore`).

If the data is to be editable, you might be best off throwing it all into a temporary sqlite table as you parse the file, attaching a `QSqlTableModel` to it, and attaching some views to it.

When the user wants to save the changes, you simply iterate over the model and dump it out to a text file.